# FreeLibrary not unhooking DLL

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, hook, createremotethread

I'm trying to hook the DLL onto a notepad process, and then unhook it. When hooked, the DLL should cause the notepad to create a hidden file whenever the user clicks "Save As" (code for this is not shown). When unhooked, that should not be the case.

However, for some reason, while I got the message "DLL unhooking from process", the DLL still is not unhooked from the notepad process, and I know this because the notepad still creates the additional file when it should not have done that.

There are no error messages on the return values whatsover (at least none that I know of), so I removed most return value checks.

**Hook**

```
HANDLE hThread;
char * pid = argv[1];
DWORD user_pid = atoi(pid);
LPCSTR Dllpath = "C:\\Users\\xxx\\Desktop....\\MyDll.dll"
LPVOID pDllPath; // Address in remote process where Dllpath will be copied to.
HMODULE hKernel32 = GetModuleHandle("Kernel32");

HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, user_pid);

char * command = argv[2];

if (strcmp(command,"hook") == 0){

    SIZE_T bytesWritten = 0;

    //Allocate memory to target process, and write dll to the allocated memory.
    pDllPath = VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, NULL,strlen(DllPath)+1, MEM_RESERVE|MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);

    // Write DLL hook name
    WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, pDllPath, (LPCVOID)DllPath, strlen(Dllpath)+1,&bytesWritten);

    // Load Dll to remote process
    hThread = CreateRemoteThread(hProcess, NULL,0,(LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)GetProcAddress(hKernel32, "LoadLibraryA"), pDllPath,0,NULL);

    WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);

    //Clean up
   CloseHandle(hThread);
   VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, pDllPath, strlen(DllPath+1, MEM_RELEASE);

else if (strcmp(command,"unhook")==0){
    InlineUnhook(); //Call unhook inside the dll itself
}

}
```

**Unhook (inside the dll itself)**

```
HANDLE __stdcall InlineUnhook(){

HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, GetCurrentProcessId());
LoadLibrary("C:\\Users\\xxx\\Desktop...\\MyDll.dll);
HMODULE hLibModule = GetModuleHandleA ("C:\\Users\\xxx\\Desktop...\\MyDll.dll);

HANDLE hThread = CreateRemoteThread(hProcess, NULL,0,(LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)GetProcAddress(hKernel32, "FreeLibraryAndExitThread"), (void *)(hLibModule,0),0,NULL);

if (hThread == NULL){
    OutputDebugStringA("CreateRemoteThread failed.");
    return -1;
}

else{
    WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);

    //Clean up
    CloseHandle(hThread);
    OutputDebugStringA("DLL unhooking from process...");

    return 0;
}
}
```

Comment: Please don't deface your question. Once you ask a question on this site, your question and its code becomes property of the site as per the terms of service that you agreed to on joining the site.

Comment: @takeru Rolled back (again). Answers have been posted to the original question which would become meaningless after your edit. Don't do that.

Comment: As you've been told, you can't delete/deface your question. What you can do though is have your name removed from it, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96732/how-do-i-remove-my-name-from-a-post-in-accordance-with-cc-by-sa

Answer (score 3):

Your injector is calling `InlineUnhook()` directly, so it will act on the instance of the DLL that is loaded in the injector process, not the hooked process.

`FreeLibraryAndExitThread()` is not compatible with `CreateRemoteThread()`, so you can't use a remote thread to call it directly, like you can with `LoadLibraryA()`.

Inside of the DLL itself, there is no need for it to call `OpenProcess()`, `LoadLibrary()`, or `CreateRemoteThread()` for itself.  The DLL can simply call `FreeLibraryAndExitThread()` directly, like any other local function.

```
HINSTANCE hThisInst;

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    hThisInst = hinstDLL;
    ...
    return 1;
}

void __stdcall InlineUnhook()
{
    FreeLibraryAndExitThread(hThisInst, 0);
}
```

Your injector will have to use a remote thread to call `InlineUnhook()` within the context of the hooked process, rather than calling it directly.  That means you need to:

- export `InlineUnhook()` from the DLL.
- find the address of the loaded DLL within the hooked process.  If your DLL is 32bit being loaded into a 32bit target process, that address can be obtained from `GetExitCodeThread()` when `CreateRemoteThread()` is done calling `LoadLibraryA()`.  Otherwise, you will have to go hunting for the loaded address afterwards, such as by `EnumProcessModules()` or `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE)`.
- find the address of the exported `InlineUnhook()` within the hooked process.  Use `LoadLibrary()` and `GetProcAddress()` inside the injector to calculate the offset of `InlineUnhook()` within the DLL, and then apply that offset to the address of the loaded DLL within the hooked process.
- use `CreateRemoteThread()` to call `InlineUnhook()` at that calculated address.  You will have to change the signature of `InlineUnhook()` to be compatible with `CreateRemoteThread()`, eg:

```
DWORD __stdcall InlineUnhook(LPVOID)
{
    FreeLibraryAndExitThread(hThisInst, 0);
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: @takeru if you want to use `FreeLibrary()` instead of `InlineUnhook()`, then yes, that will work (using `dll_base_addr` as-is, *without* subtracting `unhook_func_addr` from it). If you want to use `InlineUnhook()` instead, then use `unhook_func_addr` by itself *without* passing it to `FreeLibrary()`, but finding that address requires a few steps, as I outlined in my answer

Comment: @takeru no, it would be more like `CreateRemoteThread(hProcess, NULL,0,(LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)unhook_func_addr, NULL,0,NULL);` where `unhook_func_addr` is calculated like `dll_base_addr + offset`, where `offset` is calculated like `lib = LoadLibrary("dll"); offset = (UINT_PTR)GetProcAddress(lib, "InlineUnhook") - (UINT_PTR)lib;`

Answer (score 1):

That's because your `InlineUnhook` call above calls the copy of the dll that is loaded into your injection process, not the one in the target process.